# Как отправить таблицу в сообщение почты в Питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть необходимость вставить таблицу в почтовое сообщение в Питоне. Как это можно организовать?
Как я понимаю, нужно преобразовать текст в html код?

```
def order_created_shop(order_id):
    """
    Задача для отправки уведомления по электронной почте при успешном создании заказа на почту магазина. 
    """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Заказ №10{}'.format(order_id)
    message = 'Добрый день, заказ №10{}. сформирован на сайте "kosmetica".'.format(order.id)
    sum_order = 0                                         
    for item in OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order):
        sum_order += round(item.quantity*item.price, 1)
        message += '\n{}, кол-во: {} шт., сумма: {} руб.'\
            .format(item.product, item.quantity, round(item.quantity*item.price, 1))
        sum_order_coupon = round(sum_order - sum_order/100*order.discount, 1)
    message += '\n\nСтоимость заказа - {} руб.'.format(sum_order)
    if order.coupon is not None:
        message += '\n\nСкидка ("{}") - {} руб.'.format(order.coupon, round(sum_order/100*order.discount, 1))
    message += '\n\nОкончательная стоимость - {} руб.'.format(sum_order_coupon)
    message += '\n\nГород {}'.format(order.city)
    message += '<html>'
    message += '<table><tr>'
    message += '<th>Имя</th>'
    message += '<th>Фамилия</th>'
    message += '<th>Отчество</th>'
    message += '</tr></table>'
    message += '</html>'

    mail_sent = send_mail(subject,
                            message,
                            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                            ['.....@mail.ru'])
    return mail_sent
```

исправленный код

```
def order_created_shop(order_id):
    """
    Задача для отправки уведомления по электронной почте при успешном создании заказа на почту магазина. 
    """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Заказ №10{}'.format(order_id)
    message = 'Добрый день, заказ №10{}. сформирован на сайте "kosmetica".'.format(order.id)
    sum_order = 0                                         
    for item in OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order):
        sum_order += round(item.quantity*item.price, 1)
        message += '\n{}, кол-во: {} шт., сумма: {} руб.'\
            .format(item.product, item.quantity, round(item.quantity*item.price, 1))
        sum_order_coupon = round(sum_order - sum_order/100*order.discount, 1)
    message += '\n\nСтоимость заказа - {} руб.'.format(sum_order)
    if order.coupon is not None:
        message += '\n\nСкидка ("{}") - {} руб.'.format(order.coupon, round(sum_order/100*order.discount, 1))
    message += '\n\nОкончательная стоимость - {} руб.'.format(sum_order_coupon)
    message += '\n\nЗаказчик:\n' 

    data = [
        ('Имя: ', f"{order.first_name}"),
        ('Фамилия: ', f"{order.last_name}"),
        ('Телефон: ', f"{order.telefon}"),
        ('Email: ', f"{order.email}"),
        ('Город: ', f"{order.city}"),
        ('Индекс: ', f"{order.postal_code}"),
        ('Адрес: ', f"{order.address}"),
        ('Создан: ', f"{order.updated}"),
        ]

    message += tabulate(data)

    html = f'''
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /></head><body><table><tr>
    <th>{order.first_name}</th>'
    <th>Фамилия</th>
    <th>Отчество</th>
    </tr></table></body></html>
    '''

    # message += html

    # mail_sent = EmailMessage(subject,
    #                         message,
    #                         settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    #                         ['boleev@mail.ru'])
    # mail_sent.content_subtype = 'html'

    mail_sent = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject,
                                message,
                                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                                ['boleev@mail.ru'])
    mail_sent.attach_alternative(html, 'text/html')
    return mail_sent
```

Comment: Добавьте исходных данных. Как собираетесь отправлять сообщение? Прикрепите код отправки сообщения, если имеется.

Comment: Вот так не выходит: `message += '<html>'
    message += '<table><tr>'
    message += '<th>Имя</th>'
    message += '<th>Фамилия</th>'
    message += '<th>Отчество</th>'
    message += '</tr></table>'
    message += '</html>'`

Comment: Прикрепите к вопросу более полный код, из этого ничего не понятно

Comment: Добавил в сообщение.

Comment: Можете воспользоваться готовым решением https://gist.github.com/ripiuk/2defb27fa633a6deb1bd328d20cc4479

Comment: Как раз читаю этот пост...

Comment: Если разобрались, лучше добавить решение отдельным ответом, а не добавлять исправленный код в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В исправленном коде вы пропустили строчку в конце функции:

```
mail_sent.send()
```

Comment: Я так пробовал уже. Выводится:  <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /></head><body><table><tr>
    <th>Михаил</th>'
    <th>Фамилия</th>
    <th>Отчество</th>
    </tr></table></body></html>

Comment: @МихаилБолеев, Вы используете Django?

Comment: @МихаилБолеев Добавил вариант для Django

Comment: Теперь письма вообще не отправляются.

Comment: @МихаилБолеев отправьте код

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @МихаилБолеев замените отправку письма на: `message = EmailMessage(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,  ['boleev@mail.ru'])
message.content_subtype = 'html'
message.send()`

Comment: @МихаилБолеев добавил ответ в ответ :)

Comment: У меня же так и есть, только вместо переменной "message" - другая (см. задокументированное).

Comment: @МихаилБолеев добавьте в конце функции `mail_sent.send()`

Comment: У меня эта функция возвращает значение. Запускается она из другого места.

Comment: Если я вместо "EmailMessage" использую "send_mail", то все работает.

Comment: Все, понял. Действительно не хватало send(). Видно это отличает эти методы отправки.

Comment: @МихаилБолеев рад что смог помочь! В следующий раз указывайте в вопросе и то место, откуда запускается функция. Так быстрее могут помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать стандартный шаблонизатор.

```
html_mess = render_to_string('<ваш шаблон:html>',
                                         context=<ваш контекст:dict>)
em = EmailMultiAlternatives(...kwargs)
em.attach_alternative(html_message, 'text/html')
em.send()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Пробую. Ругается вот на эту строку: `em = EmailMultiAlternatives(...kwargs)`

Comment: как ругается?) под kwargs - подразумеваются именованные аргументы, которые вы передаете.

Comment: Я понимаю. Но как  раз на kwargs и ругается.

Comment: вот пример `EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=title, body='.', to=client)`
title - строка, to - массив получаетелей, body - пустой потому что потом альтернативно задаем тело по html шаблону. покажите какую ошибку выводит?

Comment: Сделал вот так: `mail_sent = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject,
                                message,
                                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                                ['.........@mail.ru'])
    mail_sent.attach_alternative(html, 'text/html')`. Письма вообще не отпраляются.